# Python 2.6 - passing | char into os.system in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, os.system

I have a list of IP's that I want to run a whois (using the linux tool whois) against and only see the Country option.

Here is my script:

```
import os
import time

iplist = open('ips.txt').readlines()

for i in iplist:
        time.sleep(2)
        print "Country: IP {0}".format(i)
        print os.system("whois -h whois.arin.net + {0} | grep Country ".format(i))
```

So I want to display what IP is being ran, then I just want to see the Country info using grep. I see this error when I run it and the grep is not ran:

```
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
sh: -c: line 1: ` | grep Country '
```

this code below works so it must be an issue with my for loop:

```
 print os.system("whois -h whois.arin.net + {0} | grep Country ".format('8.8.8.8'))
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!!!!

Comment: whats it print in the print statement before your error? (Im guessing you are getting an empty string or something as i)

Comment: I see output as if I ran this: 'whois -h whois.arin.net + {0}'. it's essentially ignoring the '| grep Country'

Comment: I found a cheap work-around... I can remove "| grep Country" and add to the print above "print os.system("echo Country: IP {0}".format(i))" and then run the script like "python whois.py | grep Country"

Comment: this part ... print "Country: IP {0}".format(i)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not stripping trailing newlines from the lines you read from the file. As a result, you are passing to `os.system` a string like `"whois -h whois.arin.net + a.b.c.d\n | grep Country"`. The shell parses the string as two commands and complains of "unexpected token |" at the beginning of the second one. This explains why there is no error when you use a hand-made string such as `"8.8.8.8"`.

Add `i = i.strip()` after the sleep, and the problem will go away.

Comment: Thank you! Does the strip() method, without passing any args to it, take away all special chars from the beginning/end of the string? or only the end? thank you thank you thank you

Comment: `str.strip` returns a new string with all the whitespace (space, tab, \n, \r and such) removed from the beginning and the end of the string. This is a good idea not only for removing newlines, but also for general robustness - you don't want a trailing space ruining your script.

Comment: For more information on string methods such as `strip` and `rstrip`, see the documentation at http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip .

Answer (score 1):

user4815162342 is correct about the issue you are having, but might I suggest you replace `os.system` with `subprocess.Popen`?  Capturing the output from the `system` call is not intuitive.. should you want to result to go anywhere but your screen, you'll likely going to have issues

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

server = 'whois.arin.net'

def find_country(ip):
    proc = Popen(['whois', '-h', server, ip], stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()

    if stderr:
        raise Exception("Error with `whois` subprocess: " + stderr)

    for line in stdout.split('\n'):
        if line.startswith('Country:'):
            return line.split(':')[1].strip() # Good place for regex


for ip in [i.strip() for i in open('ips.txt').readlines()]:
    print find_country(ip)
```

Python is awesome at string handling- there should be no reason to create a `grep` subprocess to pattern match the output of a separate subprocess.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Luckily I only need to read the output on screen but I will most likely need to capture the output for reporting down the road. This is great, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try [sh](http://amoffat.github.com/sh/index.html):

```
import os
import time
import re
import sh

iplist = open('ips.txt').readlines()

for i in iplist:
    time.sleep(2)
    print "Country: IP {0}".format(i)
    print sh.grep(sh.whois(i, h="whois.arin.net"), "Country")
```